# Python Telegram bot crashes with unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, heroku, telegram

I made a simple bot for Telegram: https://github.com/diviiac/FuckBot

and I am trying to host it on Heroku. But the bot crashes with the following error:

```
File "/app/fucklist.py", line 8, in <module>
bot = telebot.TeleBot(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_mode'
```

Comment: this shoud be telebot.bot also the token should not be postet anywhere public instead should be in config file

Comment: @nbk I changed "telebot.TeleBot" to "telebot.bot" but it did not work.

Comment: Did you install the [right module](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/)? `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` - not [telebot](https://pypi.org/project/telebot/).

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Yes, I installed the module manually from Heroku console and I am getting the same error https://imgur.com/a/PoD1cSg

Comment: What's the version of the module, `print(telebot.__version__)`?

Answer (score 0):

you must use parse_mode on method send_message like this: `send_message(chat_id, text, parse_mode='HTML')`